# Shiro setUnauthorizedUrl("/403") didn't work

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

I'm using Shiro in my SpringBoot project. This is my code:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(SecurityManager securityManager) {

        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/index");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(myShiroRealm());
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyShiroRealm myShiroRealm() {
        MyShiroRealm myShiroRealm = new MyShiroRealm();
        myShiroRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(hashedCredentialsMatcher());
        return myShiroRealm;
    }

    @Bean
    public HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher() {
        HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName("md5");
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashIterations(2);
        return hashedCredentialsMatcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor advisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        advisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        return advisor;
    }
}
```

my Realm code:

```
public class MyShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Resource
    private UserInfoService userInfoService;

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = (String) token.getPrincipal();
        UserInfo userInfo = userInfoService.findByUsername(username);

        if (userInfo == null) {
            return null;
        }

        SimpleAuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(
                userInfo, //用户名
                userInfo.getPassword(), //密码
                ByteSource.Util.bytes(userInfo.getCredentialsSalt()), //salt=username+salt
                getName() //realm name
        );

        return authenticationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {

        SimpleAuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();

        for (SysRole role: userInfo.getRoleList()) {
            authorizationInfo.addRole(role.getRole());
            for (SysPermission p: role.getPermissions()) {
                authorizationInfo.addStringPermission(p.getPermission());
            }
        }

        return authorizationInfo;
    }
}
```

I have write the code of `shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");`,but it didn't work, i just got the AuthorizationException in Console.

SomeOne said that `authc` doesn't support this feature, because of the code in Shiro:

```
private void applyUnauthorizedUrlIfNecessary(Filter filter) {
    String unauthorizedUrl = this.getUnauthorizedUrl();
    if(StringUtils.hasText(unauthorizedUrl) && filter instanceof AuthorizationFilter) {
        AuthorizationFilter authzFilter = (AuthorizationFilter)filter;
        String existingUnauthorizedUrl = authzFilter.getUnauthorizedUrl();
        if(existingUnauthorizedUrl == null) {
            authzFilter.setUnauthorizedUrl(unauthorizedUrl);
        }
    }

}
```

but how can it work if i use `authc`? anyone can help me?

Comment: Is this code checked in anywhere, i'll try to pull it down and reproduce

Comment: @BrianDemers finally i used `HandlerExceptionResolver` to handle this Exception.  u can find my source on [here](https://github.com/archerLj/SpringBoot/tree/master/Shiro), but u need to remove `MyExceptionResolver` and use `shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");` again in `ShiroConfiguration`

Comment: That project seems to be missing some configuration (i.e. which repository that `com.google.code.kaptcha:kaptcha:jar:2.3` is found in)

Comment: @BrianDemers thanks for your comment, i did delete some code in that project, everybody said it can not be resolved, so i have to use `HandlerExceptionResolver `, thanks for your comment once more。